# GCC, Refactoring and variable warnings

Tags: gcc, refactoring, gcc-warning

I'm refactoring some ancient code for GCC 5.2 and I have a ton of warnings of various kinds.
Some of the kind

```
unused variable ‘var1’ [-Werror=unused-variable]
variable ‘var2’ set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]
‘arg[1]’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=maybe-uninitialized]
```

I don't understand what the compiler is complaining about in these cases.

For example for **var1** this is the situation

```
int vehicleHasZone = TRUE;
vehicleHasZone = fip->fi_fgid;
MapData(TrafficLink, tp, CheckLastZone, &vehicleHasZone);

vehicle.c:2781:9: warning: unused variable ‘vehicleHasZone’ [-Wunused-variable]
     int vehicleHasZone = TRUE;
         ^
```

This seems a fair use to me.

For **var2** here it is

```
int result = TRUE;
if (result && 
        fip->fi_status == FS_OPERATIONAL &&
            ((fip->fi_drivingmode == DM_AUTO) ||
             (fip->fi_drivingmode == DM_FIREALARM))) 
    {
            vehicleHasZone = fip->fi_fgid;
vehicle.c:2780:9: warning: variable ‘result’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     int result = TRUE;
         ^
```

This again seems fair usage to me.

Now for **var3** it's like this

```
void my func () {
    int arg[ARGMAX];
    for(i = 0; i < MAX_ACTION_ARGS; i++) {
       arg[i] = 0; /* just clear field */
    }

    foo(bar, arg[1]); // <-- arg[1] may be uninitialized in this function
}
```

All the uses mentioned by the compiler seem fair to me.
What am I not getting?

Comment: Please don't post random bits of code, post some code that we can directly copy-paste in a file to reproduce the issue. Also, you don't say which version of the compiler you are using, which is important for bugs.

Comment: Thank you for the comments @MarcGlisse, I'll see what I can do about the code as it is company stuff.

Comment: It doesn't have to be the original code. If replacing "something" with "true" and putting the code in a function is enough, you can just do that, but do make sure that it produces the warning. If we cannot reproduce the warning, most likely what you posted is missing the real reason for the issue.